# Foreach PHP Error

Tags: php, foreach

I am receiving the following foreach error on my PHP file and I have no idea how to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?

When I load the page I get this:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/public_html/merge/class/global_functions.php on line 61

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/mysite/public_html/merge/class/global_functions.php on line 89
```

Line 61 and 89 of my /class/global_functions.php are as followed:

```
Here is my code from line 61 to line 98:

    foreach($GLOBALS['userpermbit'] as $v)
    {
        if(strstr($v['perm'],'|'.$pageperm_id[0]['id'].'|'))
            return true;
    }

    //if they dont have perms and we're not externally including functions return false
    if ($GLOBALS['external'] != true) return false; return true;

}

//FUNCTION: quick perm check using perm info from the onload perm check 
function stealthPermCheck($req)
{
    #if theyre an admin give them perms
    if(@in_array($GLOBALS['user'][0]['id'], $GLOBALS['superAdmins']))
            return true;    

    if(!is_numeric($req))
    {
        #if the req is numeric we need to match a title, not a permid. So try to do that
        foreach($GLOBALS['userpermbit'] as $v)
        {
            if(stristr($v['title'],$req))
                return true;
        }
    }else{
        #check if they have perms numerically if so return true
        foreach($GLOBALS['userpermbit'] as $v)
        {
            if(strstr($v['perm'],'|'.$req.'|'))
                return true;
        }
    }

    #if none of this returned true they dont have perms, return false
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) works only if the variable is either an [`array`](http://php.net/array) or an [`object`](http://php.net/object).

If you provide something else you see the error you see:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...
```

To make that error stop, ensure that the variable you pass to `foreach` is either an `array` or an `object`.

Evil php coderz cope with it this way if they want it normally to be an array but are too lazy to check anything cauz life's too short:

```
foreach ((array) @$prunzels as $do_not_care)
{
}
```

I highly recommend it, because you use `$GLOBALS` anyway, which makes me believe you want to level up in PHP evilness.

Comment: I was warned to not use irony on the internet, so explicitly spoken: just joking.

Comment: Just put `ob_start();` as the first statement in your PHP-files and you will never see errors again.

Comment: @fragmentedreality: Uh, I guess you mean `error_reporting(0);` to never see errors again.

Comment: Yeah, that would work, too. But I thought with all the globals and stuff… In fact, I made the same mistake as you did, @hakre and used irony…

Comment: No, but your first comment seemed to be… Besides, my method works. I did not say that you would get any output at all by using it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10096/discussion-between-fragmentedreality-and-hakre)

Comment: _"foreach works only if the variable is either an array or an object."_, while you get the point across, I'd just like to point out that it _only_ works on objects that implement [Traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php).

Comment: @Kristian Antonsen: No, it works with every object, it will then iterate over the public (more correct: *visible*) properties. See [Object Iteration](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code on 69 line to this: & do same on 89

$GLOBALS['userpermbit'] : this might be blank & not being cosidered as array by foreach.

```
$u_per_arr = $GLOBALS['userpermbit'];
if(!is_array($u_per_arr)) {
 $u_per_arr = array();
}

foreach($u_per_arr as $v)
```

Answer (score 1):

`$GLOBALS['userpermbit']` is either not set or not an array. you'll need to check where it has been initialized, or whats is going wrong with it. Try to give us more context.

Comment: #set up an sql query to get their perm values (if they have no usergroup (ie theyre a guest) set group to 0)
 if(empty($GLOBALS['user'][0]['permgroup'])) 
  $usergroup = '0';
 else
  $usergroup =& $GLOBALS['user'][0]['permgroup'];

 #select usergroup permissions value
 $db->select("`title`, `perm` FROM `permtable` WHERE `id` IN({$usergroup})", $GLOBALS['userpermbit']);
 $db->kill();

Answer (score 0):

The error says, that wrong type of variable has been passed to [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) construct. The error occured in line 89.

The `foreach()` construct expects first argument to be an array. Your `$userpermbit` variable, used in line 89 as argument of `foreach()` construct seems not to be an array type.

Search your code for any occurrences of `$userpermbit` and find out where it is set. Correct it to set `$userpermbit` as an array.